# What is the optimum query for searching string appears in many columns in 1 table?

Tags: database, search, query-optimization

Ok, Say, I got a table that have 3 columns: c1, c2, c3

**C1 - C2 - C3**

 A2 - B2 - N2

 K1 - B2 - N1

 K1 - B3 - N1

 L1 - A2 - C1

Ok, when users search for any combination of A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, ... then the system can be able to pick the rows with the closet match (**it means as long as the word appears in 1 column, the system will pick it, the more words appear in more columns the closer it matches**) & order them according to the closest match

Ex1: a user searches for "K1 A2 C1 N1", the system will show:

 K1 - B2 - N1

 K1 - B3 - N1

 A2 - B2 - N2

 L1 - A2 - C1

Ex2: a user searches for "K1 A2 C1 N2 B2", the system will show:

 A2 - B2 - N2

 L1 - A2 - C1

 K1 - B2 - N1

 K1 - B3 - N1

My solution is to split the search string into separate words & then search each of these words against the columns in the table. But I am not sure it is the optimum query since the DB have to search in many loops.

So if u r expert in DB, then what is the best query in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select c1
  ,c2
  ,c3
  ,case when c1 in ('K1','A2','C1','N1') then 1 else 0 end
  +case when c2 in ('K1','A2','C1','N1') then 1 else 0 end
  +case when c3 in ('K1','A2','C1','N1') then 1 else 0 end as sortweight
from theTable
where c1 in ('K1','A2','C1','N1')
or c2 in ('K1','A2','C1','N1')
or c3 in ('K1','A2','C1','N1')  order by sortweight desc
     ,c1
     ,c2
     ,c3
```

Someone from other forum suggested the above query